# Does Corona have preprocessor statements so I can execute Lua code for specific devices?

Tags: preprocessor, coronasdk

I'm trying to get the Corona SDK to run different code for different devices such as the Fire, Nook or iOS.

Are there preprocessor statements that will allow me to detect at runtime which device is being used and execute different code for each device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here's the answer:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/11/device-detection-on-steroids/

Test for a device string.

```
    if (system.getInfo("model") == "iPad" or system.getInfo("model") == "iPhone" or   system.getInfo("model") == "iPod") then
      -- ios code here
    else
      if (system.getInfo("model") ~= "Kindle Fire") then
        -- amazon code here
      elseif (system.getInfo("model") ~= "Nook" ) then
        -- nook code here
      else
        -- google code here
      end
    end
```

Blog gives a nice method to create your own device library functions rather than using `if` statements in your code all the time.